# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace' line 75

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm putting together a tournament bracket system allowing you to drag 'winners' to the next round, and if applicable the loser is automatically transfered to his place in a losers bracket.  After each drop I'm sending to php details about the match for both individual tracking purposes as well as refilling the positions in the event it is shut down and reopened.

I ran into a problem where I was sending some unwanted characters that I used .replace() to rid myself and now everything on the winners side works fine, but anything on the losers side doesn't. Hoping someone can help me figure out the cause of this.

```
15:   $(window).load(function(){
16:     $(".make-draggable, .draggable, .drag").draggable({
17:         helper: "clone",
18:         snap: ".draggable",
19:         snapMode: "inner"
20:     });
21:     $(".draggable").droppable({
22:         drop: function(event, ui) {
23:             var elemText = ui.draggable.text();
24:             $(this).html(elemText);
25:             var outB = ui.draggable.attr('id').split("-");
26:             var pl1;
27:             var pl2;
28:             if (outB[0] == "go") {
29:                 var num = outB.length;
30:                 var loser;
31:                 var loserval;
32:                 var losloc;
33:                 var losid = outB[1];
34:                 var numchars = outB[1].length;
35:                 if (num === 2) {
36:                     var i = 1;
37:                     loser = (losid.charAt(0) + "-");
38:                     pl1 = elemText;
39:                    for (i = 1; i < numchars; i++) {
40:                         loser = (loser+losid.charAt(i));
41:                     }
42:                     loserval = $("#go-" + loser);
43:                     losloc = ("#"+losid);
44:                     $(losloc).html(loserval.text());
45:                     pl2 = loserval.text();
46:                 } else if (num === 3) {
47:                     loser = (outB[1] + outB[2]);
48:                     loserval = $("#go-" + loser);
49:                     losloc = ("#"+loser);
50:                     $(losloc).html(loserval.text());
51:                     pl1 = loserval.text();
52:                     pl2 = elemText;
53:                 }
54:             } else {
55:               var getround = $(this).attr('id');
56:       if(getround == 'winner') {
57:           pl1 = $('#winnerb').text();
58:            pl2 = $('#loserb').text();
59:          } else {
60:            var inti = ui.draggable.attr('id').substring(1);
61:            if (inti%2 == 0) {
62:               var apl =  inti - 1;
63:               pl1 = elemText;
64:              pl2 = $('#l'+apl).text();
65:               alert(apl);
66:            } else {
67:               var apl =  inti++;
68:               alert(apl);
69:              pl1 = $('#l'+apl).text();
70:              pl2 = elemText;
71:            }
72:          }
73:             }
74:             var matrou = ui.draggable.parent().attr("id").split("-");
75:             $.urlParam = function(name){
76:                 var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
77:             return results[1] || 0;
78:             }
79:             pl1 = pl1.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
80:             pl2 = pl2.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
81:             elemText = elemText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
82:             var params = 'win='+elemText+'&p1='+pl1+'&p2='+pl2+'&match='+matrou[3]+'&round='+matrou[1]+'&wloc='+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'-'+$(this).attr('id')+'&lloc='+$(losloc).parent().attr('id')+'-'+$(loserval).attr('id')+'&tid='+$.urlParam('tid');
83:             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
84:             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
85:                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
86:                 }
87:             }
88:             xmlhttp.open("POST","sub_match.php",true);
89:             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
90:             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
91:             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
92:             xmlhttp.send(params);            
93:         }
94:     });
95:   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on my phone, so it's a little hard to debug your code, but I noticed that in line 62 and 66, you are just getting an element and assign it to p1, rather than getting the text of that element. Try adding .text() at the end of that line.

Answer (score 0):

I think in line `62`

```
  pl1 = $('l'+(inti+1));
```

should be

```
  pl1 = $('l'+(inti+1)).text();
```

and in line `66`

```
pl2 = $('l'+(inti+1));
```

should be

```
pl2 = $('l'+(inti+1)).text();
```

Comment: wow, such a simple mistake that I would have never seen.  Thank you very much! Now I'm just getting a bunch of: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" which doesn't seem to be a real problem, as things are making it to the database, just have to figure out why I have a few coming in as null and a few coming in as undefined.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the: (inti+1) as inti will always be and intiger, I need to add 1 to it I imagine its taking something like 12 and making it 121 rather than 13 so I tried changing it to ++ but it didn't work. :(  I'm pretty sure the problem is in the range of lines 55-68---which was fixed with adding a #before the l---silly me

Comment: @SabminCrow what does you `getround` hold and why you're doing `getround.substring(1)`?

Comment: Items are dragged and dropped to certain divs, those divs are all named base on their location or a destination code, as when you drag a to e, b is automatically sent to x getround is the id of e which needs part of its location code parsed out by the substring. does /n work in this? I'd hate to write a wall of text since return keys a submit on the comment... I'll edit my code above, it seems everything is working fine except my addition line it's doing nothing, and when I tried inti + 1 it came out as a 2 digit number rather than single, so I guess I just don't know how to add 1 and 1